# Pagination library keeps showing place holders when loading new data (flicker)

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm using the jetpack paging [library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) with both network and data base

and enabled placed holders in the paging configuration :

```
PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(18)
                    .setPageSize(20)
                    .setInitialLoadSizeHint(20)
                    .build()
```

Sometime when I fetch a new list from network and the user has reached the end of the previous list (near end) when the library concat the old list and the new list it actually send a list of nulls (place holders) to the adapter (at least the list's end part) until it finishes calculating, then it get fixed and send the correct list and items are shown ,
this causes a flicker and effect smooth scrolling

Or when user is at the last item waiting for the next list to be loaded also a flicker occurs

hope the following drawing explains the case , - old item , * new item:

```
----
----
----
----
----
---- 
   **** 
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
   ****
```

Comment: are you getting images from the network to display in your list? The downloading time of the image would account for the time you see the placeholders.

Comment: @palako Yes I'm using fresco library to show the images , would that affect ?? I thought it is done in the background , what is the relationship between the views and the placeholders ? (nulls in the adapter's list)

Comment: Yes, if you are loading images as you scroll, the library will load them as the items are requested, and there won't be nothing to display until the image is downloaded. If the images are big enough to cause you this problem, you can either reduce them in size server side, or you are going to have to preload them on the device and have the scrolling list read them locally instead.